# odoo 15 multi company job post

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

here is the scenario :

I have 4 companies (multi company enabled)

Company A posts a job in "Recruitment" and is reflected on the Jobs Portal.

Company B,C,D posts jobs in "Recruitment" and is not reflected on the Job Portal.

When modify Record Rules--->Job Multi company rule

and add in the "Group Name" : User Type / Public all jobs posted by the companies are visible on the Job Portal.

**BUT**
at that moment all 4 companies can see the posted jobs under "Recruitment"

What I want to do is :

Any job posted under "Recruitment" from any company is to be visible on the Job Portal.
No company should see other companies posted jobs under "Recruitment"
PS: each Recruiter of the 3 companies has access to only his company. Also using odoo 15 community

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can try to create another multi company access rule for the public user's access group (i think it's called "User Types \ Portal") which has to give all read rights to jobs. And you also have to change the current multi company rule on jobs to a group rule by setting the internal user's group in it. So in the end you have to have 2 rules on model jobs, one for internal users and one for the public user (which is used on the website for non logged in users).

Comment: Thanks @CZoellner will try this tomorrow and hopefully it will solve the issue.